# Анимация SVG иконки раскрытия аккордеона

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация

Есть SVG иконка, в коде она размещена инлайном. Нужно чтобы при раскрытии аккордеона иконка морфировала из показателя вниз в показатель вверх, что-то напоминающее взмахи крыльев птицы (образно). Пример SVG ниже (обязательно использовать такой дизайн).

```
<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <g id="Artboard" stroke="#FF5F00" stroke-width="2">
                                <polyline id="Page-1" transform="translate(12, 12) rotate(90.000000) translate(-12, -12) " points="9 5 15.8461359 12 9 19"></polyline>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
```

Есть идеи, как подобное реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так легко сделать при помощи 2х сегментов а не одного.

С одним все сложнее без js уже не справится.

Наведите мышкой на галочку для запуска анимации

```html
<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" stroke="#FF5F00" stroke-width="2">
            <polyline id="left" points="-8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
            <polyline id="right" points="8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" stroke="#FF5F00" stroke-width="2">
            <polyline id="left" points="-8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
            <polyline id="right" points="8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="-12 -12 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Artboard" stroke="#FF5F00" stroke-width="2">
            <polyline id="left" points="-8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
            <polyline id="right" points="8 -8 0 0"></polyline>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<style>

polyline {
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);  
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

svg:hover polyline#left { 
  animation-name: bounceLeft;
}
svg:hover polyline#right { 
  animation-name: bounceRight;
}

@keyframes bounceLeft {
  0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }

  70% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceRight {
  0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }

  70% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

</style>
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за нужную наводку!

Comment: @NeedHate нет проблем, рад помочь